# How does Haskell have late evaluation?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I have heard that Haskell has late evaluation. However, whatever I tried to do, it seemed to evaluate it the same way any other programming language does;

consider the following code:

```
test :: Bool -> IO()
test n = do
  let y = 5
  print n

main = do
  let y = 8
  test (y == 8)
```

This code outputs:

```
True
```

- Why is this code evaluating the "y" early?
- Can I have an example of late evaluation in Haskell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First some important general information to keep in mind:

**Haskell variables are *immutable*.**
Always, without exception, and there is nothing you can do about it.

So when you're writing something like `let y = 5`, it does *never* change the value of some already existing variable. Rather, it introduces a new variable called `y` and gives it the desired value. Whether somewhere else in your program there's also a variable you happen to have called `y` is irrelevant, that's a *different* variable altogether. In fact, consider this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   let y = 1
   do let y = 2
      print y
   print y
```

The output is

```
2
1
```

In your example, the `let y = 5` statement has no effect at all and will most likely just be thrown away by the compiler altogether. In fact, if you compile with `-Wall` (as you should), GHC will tell you that:

```
/tmp/wtmpf-file30239.hs:4:7: warning: [-Wunused-local-binds]
    Defined but not used: ‘y’
  |
4 |   let y = 5
  |       ^
```

So in particular, the `y == 8` check cannot possibly be affected by any `let y =` statement you could use.

In fact more generally, lazy evaluation doesn't affect values. That's one of the great things about having a purely functional language: because everything is constant, lazy evaluation generally doesn't affect the value semantics, it only affects the order in which the same work is done – which *can* affect how fast something terminates (or whether it terminates at all), but not what value it produces when it's done. It doesn't matter whether `y == 8` is evaluated before or after the runtime enters the `test` function, and in fact the Haskell standard doesn't tell anything about it – all it tells is that if `test` ends up *not even using* the argument value then a nonterminating argument shall not prevent `test` from terminating (*non-strict semantics*). So, the following demonstrates lazy evaluation in action:

```
unobtanium :: Bool
unobtanium = unobtanium -- infinite loop

don'tTest :: Bool -> IO ()
don'tTest a = do
   putStrLn "Meh, I'm too lazy to do it."

main :: IO ()
main = do
   let y = unobtanium
   don'tTest y
```

...even though `y` cannot possibly be evaluated.

Comment: Ohhhhh. My dad was said something like that: " suppose you have `a && b` where `a` is `false`, `b` doesn't get evaluated. Haskell does that more than most programming languages", I just didn't get what he meant. ;-)

Comment: also, I didn't need to declare "`unobtanium`".

Answer (score 3):

> Why is this code doing early evaluation?

It isn't, as @leftaroundabout discussed.  The misunderstanding here is about variable scoping and not evaluation.

> can I have an example of late evaluation in Haskell?

**Infinite Lists**

I found the earliest easily grokked examples of lazy evaluation were infinite lists.  Consider the typical fibonacci sequence.  A verbose version for naming sake is:

```
fibs :: [Integer]
fibs = 0 -- First element
     : 1 -- Cons with the second element
     : zipWith (\first second -> first + second) fibs (drop 1 fibs)
         -- Cons with all other elements, dynamically computed.
```

Some people don't like computation.  An example for those people is a repeating list.  Consider a never ending linked list of 42... this can be hard to do in a useful manner in C.

```
infiniteFortyTwos = 42 :infiniteFortyTwos
```

**Errors**

Errors are perhaps the most common lazy evaluation but most people don't really realize that lazy evaluation is taking place.  Often called short-circuiting when used with boolean operation, consider the shell script:

```sh
var=$(ls /dir/that/does/not/exist 2>/dev/null || echo DNE)
```

This idiom appears all over the place in programming and development.  Perl often used `|| die "error"` in its early years.  In Haskell the types discourage mixing of evaluation and failure in this specific manner but the lazy functionality is the same.

Consider this poorly-conceived routine:

```hs
headEquals :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
headEquals v xs = not (null xs) && v == head xs
```

Or the common java and C patterns:

```c
if(ptr != NULL && *ptr == value) {
   ...
}
```

**Tie The Knot**

A much more advanced lazy evaluation technique is [tying the knot](https://wiki.haskell.org/Tying_the_Knot).  For example, pretend we want to replace all elements in a list with the smallest element in the list.  Let's pretend we have the answer while computing the answer then use the returned value as said answer:

```
minList :: [Int] -> [Int]
minList [] = []
minList (m:xs) =
    let (theMin, newList) = go theMin m xs
    in theMin : newList
  where
   go realAnswer partialAnswer []     = (partialAnswer, [])
   go realAnswer partialAnswer (y:ys) =
        let newPartialAnswer = min y partialAnswer
        in (realAnswer :) <$> go realAnswer newPartialAnswer ys
```